# I need to add, some delay, to make appear a boutton

Tags: css, button, delay, visibility

I need to add some delay to a "function",this is for a web that I am doing, and the button is already there, I only change his visibility. I've tried many things, but it didn't work. The first block is to make the button not visible, and the second to make it visible, the ideas were to add some code between, to add this delay.
Heres it the code:

```css
body.page-id-2090 #button{
    visibility: hidden;
}
body.page-id-2090 #button{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [`animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

```css
button {
  animation: show 0s both;
  /* show after 2 seconds */
  animation-delay: 2s;
}


@keyframes show {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>User agreements: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
<button>I agree</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem relay fast, I appreciate that .